# SpringBoot WAR 404 in Tomcat Container

Tags: spring, docker, war

I'm trying to dockerize my Spring Boot Application.

Here my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'


services:
    
    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        hostname: mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ######
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ######
            MYSQL_USER: ######
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ######
        volumes:
            - ./mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    
    backend:
        
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfile
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - mysql
```

My dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine AS maven

RUN mkdir -p /build

COPY pom.xml /build

COPY src /build/src

WORKDIR /build

RUN mvn -B dependency:resolve dependency:resolve-plugins

RUN mvn -DskipTests clean package

FROM tomcat:jdk8-corretto

EXPOSE 8080

RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT

COPY --from=maven /build/target/promogen.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

Inspecting backend I can see that my war is deployed. In logs I can see

```
2021 15:10:57.180 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war]
```

Inside /usr/local/tomcat/webapps dir I can see that ROOT.war and ROOT folder exists.
I'm starting docker with the following command:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

When I access localhost:8080 Tomcat says Http Status 404 - Not Found.

Here logs after executing docker-compose up:

```
➜  PromogenServer git:(master) ✗ docker-compose up --build
Building backend
[+] Building 3.3s (16/16) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from dockerfile                                                                                                       0.4s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                          0.4s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/tomcat:jdk8-corretto                                                                                    1.8s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.8.4-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine                                                                   1.7s
 => [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/tomcat:jdk8-corretto@sha256:e78680bd172c7388fb9ed123423f671c2815560412ad2df8cc73f79b7922890e                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                          0.3s
 => => transferring context: 37.39kB                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [maven 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.8.4-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine@sha256:d7d5ef47f898d0ef33fb472dc63fcc67face715e337efd1728107fc9e195388d       0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/3] RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [maven 2/7] RUN mkdir -p /build                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [maven 3/7] COPY pom.xml /build                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [maven 4/7] COPY src /build/src                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [maven 5/7] WORKDIR /build                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [maven 6/7] RUN mvn -B dependency:resolve dependency:resolve-plugins                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [maven 7/7] RUN mvn -DskipTests clean package                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=maven /build/target/promogen.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war                                                   0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                     0.3s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:6a591e6448a22aefbd44a2c5b62940acdb46b581005de8e5fe940113c6de7acf                                                               0.1s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/promogenserver_backend                                                                                                  0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Starting promogenserver_mysql_1 ... done
Starting promogenserver_backend_1 ... done
Attaching to promogenserver_mysql_1, promogenserver_backend_1
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20 15:19:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20 15:19:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20 15:19:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:40.133565Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27) starting as process 1
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:40.158480Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:40.214360Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.185 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.14
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.192 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 2 2021 22:01:36 UTC
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.0.14.0
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.10.47-linuxkit
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.194 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.194 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto/jre
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.195 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_312-b07
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.195 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Amazon.com Inc.
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.196 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.196 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.212 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.212 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.213 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.213 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.213 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.234 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.31] using APR version [1.7.0].
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.234 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:42.248 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020]
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:43.623 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:43.690 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [2225] milliseconds
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:43.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:43.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.14]
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:43.873 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war]
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:45.785479Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:47.572660Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:47.610076Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:48.760762Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:48.760872Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:48.778784Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:48.779013Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:48.843650Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:49.192746Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysql_1    | 2021-12-20T15:19:49.193439Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.27'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:51.902 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:52.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war] has finished in [8,166] ms
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:52.054 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
backend_1  | 20-Dec-2021 15:19:52.081 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [8390] milliseconds
```

EDIT 1:

I changed tomcat image to

```
tomcat:8.5-jdk17-corretto
```

And now Spring application starts but complains about mysql connection:

```
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

EDIT 2:

I solved it. I changed my application.properties from

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/promogen
```

to

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/promogen
```

Where mysql is the String I used in services in docker-compose.yml file

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Solved it.

Look edits.